Taking tuples from text file {ython 3.11.2
I'm making a game where the level loads in via a txt file, but I can't take the lines out of the file so my program can read it.
This is the extraction code:
def create_level():
    global Level
    Level = []
    file = open("level_file.txt","r")
    lines_in_file = file.readlines()
    #Level = lines_in_file
    number_of_lines = len(lines_in_file)
    #print(number_of_lines)
    for line in range(number_of_lines):
        to_write = lines_in_file[line]
        Level = Level + ["(" + to_write.rstrip("\n") + ")"]
    print(Level)

and the file looks like this
-30,-30,400,40
40,40,200,40
0,550,600,40

The output O want is:
[(-30,-30,200,40),(40,40,200,40),(0,550,600,40)]
But the output I get is:
['(-30,-30,200,40)', '(40,40,200,40)', '(0,550,600,40)']

How is the third value in the first line transformed from 400 to 200 in the output?

Use of return from function instead of a global variable, is preferable.

Your input file is effectively a CSV. However, as its structure is so simple, there's really no need to introduce additional modules to process it.
I suggest:
def create_level():
    with open("level_file.txt") as fd:
        return [tuple(map(int, row.split(","))) for row in fd]

print(create_level())

Output:
[(-30, -30, 400, 40), (40, 40, 200, 40), (0, 550, 600, 40)]


You ask for a list of tuples. Your text file is a comma separated file, so therefore I suggest a .csv file as input:
import csv

def level_list(filename):
    ll = []
    with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
        levelreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in levelreader:
            ll.append(tuple(int(x) for x in row))    
    return ll

if __name__ == "__main__":
    levels = level_list("levels.csv")
    # levels = level_list("levels.txt")
    print(levels)


Output:
[(-30, -30, 400, 40), (40, 40, 200, 40), (0, 550, 600, 40)]

PS: It works also if your input file is named levels.txt instead of levels.csv!

For a list of levels, read and append each line as a tuple of ints to the list:
def create_level():
    levels = []
    with open("level_file.txt","r") as f:
        while line := f.readline():
            levels.append(tuple(int(n) for n in line.rstrip().split(',')))
    
    # levels = [(-30, -30, 400, 40), (40, 40, 200, 40), (0, 550, 600, 40)]
create_level()

